# Customizing the encryption of chat texts data to the backend db

Tags: openfire

We have the requirement to use Vault to encrypt and decrypt the actual chat texts themselves. So basically just before we actually store the chat messages, we will call vault and encrypt it and then store the cipher text.

Likewise, on retrieving the cipher text form the DB, we use vault to decrypt it.

Is this possible via settings or do I need to either create some form of plugin or hack the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Note that by default, Openfire does not store messages in a database. It will only do so for messages that were delivered to offline people, or when archiving is enabled.

None of this functionality provides an API specific to your purpose. There are various ways in which you could implement this:

- Modify/replace the code in all places where database-interaction takes place
- Create a PacketInterceptor, that encrypts *all* messages that are flowing through Openfire upon entry, and decrypt them again upon exit

None of these will be easy to do, though!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So in the case of storing offline messages, does it later remove them when the end user sees them?  My basic problem is the need to imply a char server and at first look, OpenFire seems to do it all.  My security people provided the caveat that any storage of messages must use encryption.

Comment: Yes, offline messages are removed after they've been read. Message storage takes place in the database that you've configured, to which you can apply any number of security aspects. The messages themselves are stored as plain text in the database though.